# Extra argument in callのエラー対策について(alamofire?)

Tags: swift, alamofire

Extra argument 'error' in callとエラーが出ます。swiftをさわって数日なのでわかりません、どなたかご助力お願いします。

```
import UIKit 
import MapKit 
import Alamofire
class ViewController:
    UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {
        @IBOutlet weak var map1: MKMapView!
        @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
        @IBAction func nextbutton(_ sender: Any) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "recommend", sender: nil)
        } 
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad() 
        }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
                // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
    }
func getArticles() {//←エラーが出る箇所
    Alamofire.request(.POST,"https://www.google.com") 
}
}
```

Comment: 質問文に貼られたコードは最後の閉じカッコ `}` が余分に見えますが、意図した通りでしょうか？

Comment: いいえ違います！修正して見ます！

Answer (score 0):

`Alamofire`の`Useage.md`によると、`request`メソッドの構文は、

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.google.com", method: .post)
```

の様ですが、エラーが起きているのはコンパイルエラーでしょうか？それともコンパイルは通って、実行時エラーでしょうか？